# XQuery maps: append value with the same key to the existing map

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, exist-db

I have **these maps** (they were constructed from another query):

```
let $my_maps :=
    (
        map {
            "book_id": "id_1",
            "title": "Some title",
            "author": "Some author",
            "date": "Some dates"
        },
        map {
            "book_id": "id_2",
            "title": "Some title",
            "author": "Some author",
            "date": "Some dates"
        }
    )
```

And I have **this XML file**:

```
<book xml:id="id_1">
    <introduction>texte of introduction</introduction>
    <chapter id="1">texte of  chapter 1</chapter>
    <chapter id="2">texte of chapter 2</chapter>
    <notes>texte of notes</notes>
    <conculsion>texte of conclusion</conculsion>
</book>
```

**What I want**:

- extract from my XML file only few parts (for this example, let's say `introduction` and `notes`)
- **append these parts (with the key "text") from the XML file to the existing map with corresponding id's value.**

My **ongoing XQuery**:

```
let $grouped_map := 
    (
        for $id in $my_maps?book_id
        
        for $book_part in collection("path_to_my_collection")/book[@xml:id = $id]//(introduction | notes)
     
        return 
            map:merge((
                $my_maps[?book_id = $id],
                
                for $part in $book_part
                group by $xml_id := $part/ancestor::book/@xml:id
                return
                    map:entry("text", $part)
                ))
    )

return
 $grouped_map
```

**Ongoin result**:

```
1
map {
    "book_id": "id_1",
    "title": "Some title",
    "author": "Some author",
    "date": "Some dates",
    "text": <introduction>texte of introduction</introduction>
}
2
map {
    "book_id": "id_1",
    "title": "Some title",
    "author": "Some author",
    "date": "Some dates",
    "text": <notes>texte of notes</notes>
}
```

**Expected result**:

```
1
map {
    "book_id": "id_1",
    "title": "Some title",
    "author": "Some author",
    "date": "Some dates",
    "text": (<introduction>texte of introduction</introduction>, <notes>texte of notes</notes>)
}
```

I also tried  `map {'duplicates' : 'combine'}`:

```
let $grouped_map := 
    (
        for $id in $my_maps?book_id
        
        for $book_part in collection("path_to_my_collection")/book[@xml:id = $id]//(introduction | notes)
     
        return 
            map:merge((
                $my_maps[?book_id = $id],
                map:entry("text", $book_part),
                map {'duplicates' : 'combine'}
                ))
    )

return
 $grouped_map
```

But the result stays the same. (By the way, I use eXsit and I didn't see in [its documentation about map functions](https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/fundocs/view.html?uri=http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map&location=java:org.exist.xquery.functions.map.MapModule) any mention of `map {'duplicates' : 'combine'}`, so not sure they allow this...)

Comment: You start with a sequence of maps and want a sequence of maps as the result? Or a single map?

Comment: It doesn’t really matter for me, I just want to group all “text” by id. Counter question: on the assumption that I can have a hundreds maps and, in my final return, I want to construct some xml output from these maps, what is best for query performance? To have one map with hundreds nested maps or to have hundreds “little” maps?

Comment: I don't know much about exist-db so I won't make any guesses about the performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds to me as if you just want

```
for $map in $my_maps
let $books := collection("path_to_my_collection")/book[@xml:id = $map?book_id]
return map:put($map, 'text', $books ! (.//introduction | .//notes))
```

That would put a `text` item into each map of the input, the value might be an empty sequence if there are no matching books.

Comment: It works like a charm! Thank you very much!